# Storing a COUNT of values in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table with data along the (massively simplified) lines of:

```
User | Value
-----|------
UsrA |   100
UsrA |   102
UsrB |   100
UsrA |   100
UsrB |   101
```

and, for reasons far to obscure to go into, I need to store the `COUNT` of each value in a table for future retrieval - ending up with something like

```
User | Value100Count | Value101Count | Value102Count
-----|---------------|---------------|--------------
UsrA |             2 |             0 |             1
UsrB |             1 |             1 |             0
```

However, there could be up to 255 different `Value`s - meaning potentially 255 different `ValueXCount` columns. I know this is a horrible way to do things, but is there an easy way to get the data into a format that can be easily `INSERT`ed into the destination table? Is there a better way to store the `COUNT` of values per user (unfortunately I do need to store this information; grabbing it from the source table each time isn't an option)?

Comment: Better to normalize your table

Comment: either keep your totals acurate ( update/delete/create them when they change on the main table ) and sync them once overnight ( nightly job ) - or... as Fabio said, normalize your table, a well written join/group by statement should give you COUNTs quite fast

Comment: simple script with loops will do

Comment: I agree that it is best to normalize the data but if the list of values is static you can use the pivot syntax if you are using an Oracle DB.
http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1.php

Comment: Unfortunately the "source" table is the output from a legacy, plumbed-in system, and doing anything to change the format is out of the question :(

Comment: YOu can also try a PIVOT statement as last resort, but try to change your table structure.

Comment: Ah... classic management who thinks PIVOT is easy hey? since you didn't specify RDBMS - in oracle you have pivot and in mysql you don't - but unless you wish to envolve server side scripting, i'd advise you to manually insert the 255 values in a huge`count(case..)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole thing isn't very pretty, but you know that, rather than your table with 255 columns I'd consider setting up another table with:

```
User | Value | CountOfValue
```

And set a primary key over User and Value.

You could then insert the count's for given user/value combos into the CountOfValue field

As I said, the design is horrible and it feels like you would be better off starting from scratch, normalizing and doing counts live.

Answer (score 0):

Check out indexed views. You can maintain the table automatically, with integrity and as a bonus it can get used in queries that already do count(*) on that data.